# How to apply all Django migrations initially

Tags: python, django

In Django < 1.7, you could apply all schema changes to a blank database by running:

```
manage.py syncdb --all
```

However, in Django >= 1.7, even though the `syncdb` command is technically still there, this functionality seems to have been removed, since the `--all` option is no longer available. The command itself appears to be just a wrapper around `migrate`, so running it just applies all migrations individually, which can take a huge amount of time if you have a lot of migrations.

I have a script that initializes a blank database with my schema, and what used to take a minute now takes nearly 30, which is an insane performance drop for an upgrade. Is there any way to get the old functionality back?

Comment: what is the problem when you are using makemigrations? it generally applies migrations for all apps

Comment: @Exprator, I have a lot of inter-app dependencies, so even though I've flattened my migrations, makemigrations results in several apps have 2 or 3 initial migrations. Running migrate causes each to be run instead of a single one, and it's significantly slower than in 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `python manage.py makemigrations` so in the migration folder, a doc will be created. In there you can review all the migrations that will be applyed when you run the next command.

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This will applay all the migrations of all the apps installed in your settings.

Comment: y would recommendyou to make the my first app tutorial in django site, so you update a little your knowledte, 1.7 to 1.13 its a large road

Comment: *Why* should OP try any of this? Are you expecting to use OP's production environment to "see what happens"? You can improve your answer by identifying and explaining what the *actual problem* is and *why* your post should be considered a solution to it.

Comment: oh, sorry my bad, makemigrations actually create all the migrations initially in a doc so you can review them and migrate, apply that migrations :D